# Не работает window.onload после изменения location.href

Tags: javascript

```
function registration() {
    var message = new Message(null);
    message.text = $("#sysPassword").val();
    message.options = false;
    if ($("#regPassword").val() == $("#repPassword").val())
        message.options = true;
    var customer = new Customer(null);
    customer.login = $("#regLogin").val();
    customer.password = $("#regPassword").val();
    customer.name = $("#name").val();
    customer.surname = $("#surname").val();
    customer.phone = $("#phone").val();
    var data = new Data(customer,message);
    var formData = new FormData;
    formData.append("client", JSON.stringify(data));
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/registration", false);
    xhr.send(formData);
    var data = new Data(null);
    data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (data.message.options) {
        document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/";
        alert("Connect!");
        window.onload = function() {
            alert("HelloWorld!");
            outputMessage(data.message.text);
        };
    }
    else {
        "http://localhost:8080/static/pages/registration.html";
        outputMessage(data.message.text);
    }
}
```

На страницу переходит, `Connect!` вижу, `HelloWorld!` - нет.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас `if (data.message.options){` где находится? в какой-нибудь функции или dom ready?  вообще `window.onload = function(){` должно быть во внешнем мире а не во внутреннем..... то есть за пределами ифов.....типа `<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    alert( 'Документ и все ресурсы загружены' );
  };  if (data.message.options){
    document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/";
    alert("Connect!");   
}  
</script>`

Comment: Если я правельно понял можно так: $(window).load(function() {}

Comment: закомментируй строку `document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/";`

Comment: Это отдельный js документ, это часть кода, ссылку закоментить не могу, без нее нет смысла, но на страницу эту переходить и первый alert вижу.....

Comment: window.onload не вызоветкся т.к. вы прерываете загрузку страницы делая редирект document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/";

Answer (score 1):

После смены `location.href` происходит переход на новую страницу. Однако в некоторых браузерах код (не асинхронный) всё же выполнится до конца до перехода. Но это не гарантируется, и рассчитывать на этот код не стоит.

Если вам нужно выводить `HelloWorld!`, то код

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("HelloWorld!");
    pagesMessage("indexOutput", data.message.text);
};
```

должен быть расположен на странице, загружаемой по адресу `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: Я привел полный код...Так, возможно, проще обьяснить будет)

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров а что ещё нужно объяснить?

Comment: Как вызвать pagesMessage после обработки данных полученых из сервера, если строка, в которой это будет выводиться находится на location.href, а перехожу я на location.href из другой страницы. Получается, что мне нужно вывести сообщение на странице, которая еще не загрузилась.

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров вынести указанный код с `window.onload` на localhost. Функцию `pagesMessage` тоже скопировать на localhost.

Comment: функция одна общая на все страницы...

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров скопируйте её на нужные страницы. Вынесите это всё в отдельную библиотеку, например, и используйте на нужных страницах. Или с фреймами попробуйте работать.

Comment: Я, тугой в скрипте.Суть в следующем: из страницы регистрации данные улетают на сервер, он их валидит возвращает JSON, который парсится и, в зависимости от данных, которые прилетели либо остаешься на тойже страницы и выводишь сообщение об ошибке, либо переходишь на авотризацию с сообщением регистрация удачная."Регистрация удачная" не появляется, поскольку,если я правильно понял, страница не загрузилась.Это сообщение и есть pagesMessage передаваемое в тег <output> на всех страницах с разными сообщениями.Еще раз простите за тупость,но как реализовать не знаю.Я думал надо дать загрузиться странице

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров вы можете спросить об этом отдельным вопросом. Данный вопрос был "почему не выводится `HelloWorld!`?", и ответ на него дан. Но всё же отвечу, что вы можете данные передавать между страницами. Например, с помощью GET-параметра. Или через cookie, если домен тот же. А ещё если вы плохо разбираетесь в JS, то можно что-то почитать про него.